# Dynamically check the condition for iteration in for loop - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

**Example of my code:** (Actual code is very long. Could be found in edit history)

```
X = {'a','b','c','d'}

for i = 1:length(X)
     if X(i) == 'a'    %// for example
          X(i)=[];
     end
end
```

Why didn't the counter stop at 3rd iteration? It tried to continue till 4th iteration and generated the following error :

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

But as the first element 'a' was deleted, The actual size of array has become 3 (instead of 4). Shouldn't the 'looping' be stopped after the 3rd iteration?

Comment: I don't have matlab now, but i will check that tonight , interesting ... ;)

Comment: What is the length of region_L?

Comment: before the loop length(region_L)= 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean

```
X = ['a','b','c','d']
```

(with square brackets), so `X` is a char array (string), not a cell array

---

The problem is that within the loop you remove one entry of `X`, so `X` is left with `3` entries. Thus, when you try to access its `4`th entry (at iteration `i=4`) you get an error.

This happens because the `for` exit condition is **not re-evaluated at each iteration**. At the `for` statement you say that `i` has to run from `1` to `4` (`4` is the value of `length(X)` **at that time**), and that's what happens.

To achieve what you want you probably need a [`while`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop. The `while`-loop condition is **evaluated after each iteration, using the current values for the variables**, to determine whether a new iteration should take place or not. So in the following code only `3` iterations occur, and you get no errors:

```
i = 1;
while i<=length(X)
    if X(i) == 'a'
        X(i) = [];
    else
        i = i + 1;
    end
end
```

The counter `i` should be incremented only if no element of `X` has been removed. Thanks to @matlabgui for the catch.

Comment: @LuisMendo you need to add a `continue` after the `X(i) = []` - consider the case where `X = ['a' 'a' 'c' 'd']`

Comment: @matlabgui Thanks! You are right, I didn't think about that. I've edited the answer. Now I increment the counter `i` only if no element has been removed. I think that's the same as `continue` but I find it clearer.

Comment: @LuisMendo - no problem! :)  Yes counting on the else has the same desire - I have used both methods - depends on the bigger picture of your code!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your code is:

```
X={'a','b','c','d'}

for i = 1:length(X)
     if X{i} == 'a'    %for example
          X(i)=[]
     end
end
```

When `X{i}` == 'a' you are removing `X(i)` -> i.e. X becomes 3 long instead of 4.  But you loop is programmed to go to the length of X before you started (i.e. 4).

In this type of situation you can do the loop in reverse:

```
X={'a','b','c','d'}

for i = length(X):-1:1
     if X{i} == 'a'    %for example
          X(i)=[]
     end
end
```

Another method is to store an inedx in the loop and then remove at the end:

```
X={'a','b','c','d'}

index = false(length(X),1);
for i = 1:length(X)
     if X{i} == 'a'    %for example
          index(i)= true;
     end
end
X(index) = [];
```

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem but I have to start my loop at the right direction : for i = 1 : length(X)

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Arrays start with 1
and then you have to decrease the end of the loop because your vektor got smaller or get a second variable.

And I wasn't able to compare chars.. but with numbers it worked

so it would be

```
j=0
for i = 1:length(X)
     j=j+1;
     if X(j) == 'a'    %for example
          X(j)=[];
          j=j-1;
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get error since Matlab's index of any array starts at 1, and you did the for-loop starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate the problem, the code uses cells, and you cannot index the 0th cell. So I edited to code to look like this:

```
for i = 1:length(X)
     if X{i} == 'a'    %for example
      X{i}=[];
     end
end

>>X = 

[]    'b'    'c'    'd'
```

No problems detected

EDIT: based on your code, you are deleting the cells while running this loop; try deleting the value in your cell instead of deleting the cell,you want to use curly brackets {} instead of [], and if you want to delete the empty cells, simply do it at the end using:

```
X(~cellfun('isempty',X))
```

Comment: You're right, but i have more complex code I have tryed to explain with simple code ( I will edit and put my code maybe you will see the problem ) thank you

Comment: @Devel I have edited my answer, please check if it makes any difference